# Windows Phone 8.1 memory issue

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

I have 8 large blocks of memory (28mb each). They are stored in unmanaged (native) code. And I want to dump them into files. But after I dump them, they are not released and I have 230mb busy memory, which make not available to continue running my app. Further thrown OutOfMemory.
Here my dumping code:

```
//* Dump input images
for (int i = 0; i < frames.Length; i++)
{
    StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(
        string.Format("FRAME_{0}.yuv", i), 

    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        byte[] image = SwapHeap.copyFromHeap(frames[i].ImagePtr, (int)frames[i].Width * (int)frames[i].Height * 3 / 2);
        await stream.WriteAsync(image, 0, image.Length);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
        image = null;
    }
}
...
System.GC.Collect();
```

And native code to get `byte[]` from `int` pointer:

```
Array<uint8>^ SwapHeap::copyFromHeap(const int ptr, int length) 
{
    Array<uint8>^ res = ref new Array<uint8>(length);
    memcpy(res->Data, (byte*)ptr, length);
    return res;
}
```

I free memory in native code using `free((byte*)ptr);` and it's ok. But I can't understand, why `byte` arrays are not released?

P.S. I can dump data using native code, but I want to understand how GC works (msdn I've already read).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130382/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net/17131389#17131389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like problem in `Stream` class. As far as I can understood from different tests, it locks `byte` array, which is written to stream. And it's not closed or released outside `using` block.
If use `FileIO` instead of `Stream` and change dumping code to:

```
// Dump input images
for (int i = 0; i < frames.Length; i++)
{
    StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
        string.Format("FRAME_{0}.yuv", i), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    byte[] image = SwapHeap.copyFromHeap(frames[i].ImagePtr, (int)frames[i].Width * (int)frames[i].Height * 3 / 2);
    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, image);
    image = null;
    file = null;
}
```

Everything is fine.